# array_merge или $array[]

Tags: php, алгоритм

Задался вопросом: а что быстрее (и есть ли вообще разница, учитывая, что это в цикле на тысячи итераций) между следующими конструкциями:

```
$items = array_merge($items, self::parse($html)); // parse() возвращает массив, типа тех данных, что хранятся в $items (ключи итогого ассоциативного массива идентичны).
```

и

```
$items[] = self::parse($html);
```

Я не прошу описать функции, мне нужно узнать, что лучше использовать. До меня использовалась array_merge. Не избыточно ли?

Comment: может `array_push`  вы имели в виду а не `array_merge`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_merge` часто используют для задания элементов (опций) по-умолчанию. Например если во втором массиве может не оказаться значения с некоторым ключем, отсутствие которого в дальнейшем коде даст ошибку.

В данном контексте вместо

```
$items = array_merge($items, self::parse($html));
```

можно написать

```
$items = self::parse($html) + $items;
```

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо!

Comment: @TimurMusharapov я ошибся. Внес исправления

Answer (score 4):

Разница определённо есть - `array_merge` сливает массивы, тогда как оператор `[] =` добавляет элемент массива в конец. Это совсем разные вещи, сравнивать их даже смысла нет - когда надо добавить элемент желательно использовать `[]`, это более читаемо.

`array_merge` порождает новый массив содержащий элементы обоих переданных ему массивов. При этом исходный массивы остаются неизменными.

```
php > $a1 = Array(1,2);
php > $a2 = Array(3,4);
php > var_dump(array_merge($a1, $a2));
array(4) {
  [0]=> int(1)
  [1]=> int(2)
  [2]=> int(3)
  [3]=> int(4)
}
php > var_dump($a1);
array(2) {
  [0]=> int(1)
  [1]=> int(2)
}
php > var_dump($a2);
array(2) {
  [0]=> int(3)
  [1]=> int(4)
}
```

`[] =` добавляет элемент в массив, если ему передать массив то он добавит это массив как элемент массива.

```
php > $a1[] = $a2;
php > var_dump($a1);
array(3) {
  [0]=> int(1)
  [1]=> int(2)
  [2]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> int(3)
    [1]=> int(4)
  }
}
```

Поведение `array_push` идентично поведению `[] =` за исключением того что `array_push` возвращает новое количество элементов в массиве. Не утверждаю, но подозреваю что разницы в производительности между ними нет.

Comment: в ответ примеров добавь

Comment: @Naumov добавил примеры

Comment: @MrClon ок, спасибо

Comment: @MrClon колективное творчество :D

Comment: Мм, зачем в данном случае сливать массив с другим и все это в один из них же заносить, если можно заменить на простое добавление? Опять же, повторюсь: а что быстрее (и есть ли вообще разница, учитывая, что это в цикле на тысячи итераций). То, что вы написали, и в документации написано х)

Comment: Вы описали функции, мне же нужно узнать, что лучше использовать. До меня использовалась array_merge. Не избыточно ли? Напомню: ключи итогого ассоциативного массива идентичны..

Comment: @TimurMusharapov идентичны чему? Почему вы всегда недоговариваете? В тексте вопроса можно было бы хотя бы указать примеры массивов и что именно вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: @Timur Musharapov если `array_merge` будет использоваться даже 10 тысяч раз, при добавлении элемента в конец - врядли это повлияет на производительность.  Скорее алгоритм, который так делает можно назвать весьма сомнительным.

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` объеденяет 2 и более массива и возвращает результирующий массив.

`[]`, близкий аналог `array_push`, добавляет одно значение в конец массива. и возвращает, это присвоенное значение.

Как их вообще можно сравнивать?